# replace special characters in a column in postgresql using pgadmin

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to replace a column with these characters --> "{,

I tried using both replace and regex_replace, I am getting the following error.

```
update mytable
   set address = replace(address, ',','_');
```

this is the error I get.

> ```
> ERROR:  function replace(character varying[], unknown, unknown) does not exist
> LINE 1: select replace(address,',','_') from mytable.
>                ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. 
> You might need to add explicit type casts.
> SQL state: 42883
> Character: 8
> ```

Comment: What is the data type of the `address` column?

Comment: Your column `address` is an array and the various replace functions do not work with arrays.